# Query dynamoDB by performing IN operation (begins_with (condition-expression )) on sort key

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am in a situation to query dynamoDB, 
where I have the hashKey (objectId) and I have the prefix for sortKey (versionId).

I would like to achieve something like below:

```
QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec();
querySpec.withKeyConditionExpression("objectId = :v_objectId and (annotationIdVersion IN (:v_objectId, begins_with(versionId, :v_prefix)))")
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":v_objectId", objectId).withString(":v_prefix", "v0_"));
table.query(querySpec);
```

In the above example, I am trying to check if my versionId is equal to either "objectId" or "some_prefix".

I found that begins_with function in dynamoDB helps to achieve the query based on the prefix.

But I am not sure if the IN operator takes the begins_with function. I am looking for any suggestion on achieving the above use case.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try the above on a real table?

Comment: Yes, It threw an exception saying I cant use begins_with in this expression

Comment: you can use composite keys for sort key, like objectId and some_prefix becomes version#objectId and version#some_prefix respectively, then you can query both of them in a single request

Answer (score 0):

sort key does not support "IN", only FilterExpression does

so you may query objectId = :v_objectId, and then filter

```
{
        "TableName": "tpl_name",
        "KeyConditionExpression": " objectId = :objectId_value ",
        "FilterExpression": "( annotationIdVersion IN (:v1,:v2,:v3 ) )",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":objectId_value": {
                "S": "myobjid"
            },
            ":v1": {
                "S": "a"
            },
            ":v2": {
                "S": "b"
            },
            ":v3": {
                "S": "c"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you understand my question, I am asking if I can use begins_with function under IN operation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this. See the [documentation for condition expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html).

The relevant syntax, at the top of the page, is:

```
condition-expression ::=
    operand IN ( operand (',' operand (, ...) ))
```

Where an *operand* is defined as a top-level attribute name, or a document path that references a nested attribute. In other words, only attributes are supported, and not functions like `begins_with`.